# Apply a block to all objects of an NSArray

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-blocks

Is there a way to apply a block to all the objects of an array?

Let's say I have an amazing block:

```
void (^myAmazingBlock)(NSNumber *) = ^(NSNumber *aFooNumber) {
    NSLog(@"Log message from an Amazing Block: %@", aFooNumber);
};
```

To apply my block to all the objects of my array, this works:

```
for (NSNumber *aNumber in myArray) {
    myAmazingBlock(aNumber);
}
```

Is it possible to get rid of the fast enumeration loop, and have something similar in the spirit to:

```
[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.^myAmazingBlock"]; // This code doesn't work. It's just to show the style of what I'm trying to write.
```

I don't have any specific use in mind ; I was just being curious of the other possible ways to write this.

---

**Edit:**

It's possible to use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` (Thank you paulbailey).
You then have to declare your block like this:

```
void (^myAmazingBlock2)(id, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(id aFooNumber, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Amazing BLOCK 2 %@", aFooNumber);
};

[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:myAmazingBlock2];
```

Unfortunately, the fast enumeration loop is still the most readable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` perhaps? Obviously you'd have to adapt the parameters of your block to match those specified.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html